# How can I make GameObjects translate across the screen smoothly in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

Basically, I have a game where tickets appear at the top of the screen. When a ticket is completed, it gets destroyed, and if there's a gap between the remaining tickets, the tickets slide down to fill in the gap. I actually have it working just fine, but they kind of just jump to the positions and it doesn't look very pretty.

How can I move the objects to their target position smoothly? I've tried messing with `Lerp` and `Smoothdamp`, but both of those seem to be producing strange results (tickets go all over the place. Here's the relevant code I'm working with:

```
    public void SlideRail()
    {
        ticketList.RemoveAll(x => x == null);
        int count = ticketList.Count;

        for (int i = destroyedIndex; i < ticketList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (ticketList[i] != null)
            {
                ticketList[i].transform.Translate(Vector3.left * 35);
                ticketList[i].GetComponent<Ticket>().index--;
            }
        }
        indexer = railPosition.IndexOf(ticketList.Last().GetComponent<Ticket>().item_pos);
        up = false;
    }
```

DestroyedIndex is the index of the object that was destroyed (so that we only move the objects after it in the list)
Up is a flag that activates SlideRail(), when its set to false the method ends and the next method continues.

SlideRail is then called in the Update() method:

```
    void Update()
    {
        if (up && ticketList.Count > 2)
            SlideRail();


        if (Time.time > nextTicket)
        {
            nextTicket = Time.time + timeBetweenTickets;
            StartCoroutine(WaitToPrint());
            CreateTicket();
            UpdatePosition();
        }
    }
```

I feel like I should be able to do this using `Translate`, but I must be missing something.

Answer (score 1):

With movement like this you should usually include `Time.deltaTime` (as a factor in translate) to bind the movement to the frame rate. [Edit: Translate this sentence to framerate-independant, that's what I meant.]

Now, to the actual point, it looks like you do the movement in just one frame and thus you get this jump (you always set `up` to false at the end of `SlideRail`).

A possible way of doing this is to specify a target position upon trigger (task complete, need to push over) and than keep calling `ticketList[i].transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(ticketList[i].transform.position, targetPosition, speed * Time.deltaTime);` for each object (framed by a "reached target position" check, e.g. using `if(Vector3.Distance(ticketList[i].transform.position, targetPosition) > someThreshold)`. You can add an else to this to directly set the position when in threshold range (make the threshold small so it's not visible, e.g. 0.1f), though you usually only need this for non-linear functions like lerp which slow down at the end and can stall. [Edit: Because of floating point imprecision it's actually mostly always a good idea to use a threshold.]

Comment: This is the best suggestion I've had so far, although I'm still not sure how to implement it. To test, I made a random square prefab and put that code you suggested in the update function just to see if it would work. Sure enough, it did. This is because, I assume, the Update() is checking that if condition every frame. But SlideRail() is called during update, but the conditions aren't checked every frame in that same manner. Am I correct in thinking that? And if so, how can I check that if condition for each element in the list? I put the condition in a while loop but that crashed Unity.

Comment: *`you should usually include Time.deltaTime (as a factor in translate) to bind the movement to the frame rate.`* Unbind it, actually. You want movement to be *frame rate independent* which is why using deltaTime is good.

Comment: @Draco18s Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: @Matt Well, `Update` is already a loop so you don't need an extra loop (except for doing it for all elements of course). In `Update` you check `if(up == true)`, now, at the end of `SlideRail` you set it to false without any condition, so, with the code provided you will only go into `SlideRail` once. Instead you want to put the `up = false` into a condition that asks if the object (or potentially all, would need some counter or similar for that) reached the target position and just set `up = false` then.

Comment: Another option would be to use a coroutine instead of update like in the answer of ATHellboy. That one does need the while-loop to do the same as update.

Answer (score 0):

Using [iTween](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/animation/itween-84), it can be simplified into a one line call:

```
iTween.MoveTo(someGameObject, iTween.Hash("y", targetY, 
             "islocal", true,"easetype", iTween.EaseType.spring, 
            "time", 0.2f));
```

[image]

Comment: So, I'm intrigued. I recently started coding in C#, retooling my Flash Games to Unity. Getting back in the game. Please explain "someGameObject" and "targetY". While this is a pretty example. I don't know how to apply this. As I finally got the import to recognized that it's actually in and VSCode "sees" it now... I'm moving my someGameObject to a location that I know; I actually know the x/y coordinates. But that's not what this function wants. So I created an object to "seek" and put it on the stage. move someGameObject to this targetY object? I tried and not working either.

Comment: It seems it's for 3D objects only? If so, is there a way to use this extension/plugin for a 2D game, using 2D Game Objects?

Answer (score 0):

I've wrote this piece of code for myself before, maybe it helps you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveTime;
    public AnimationCurve moveSpeedCurve;
    public AnimationCurve movePositionCurve;

    public void StartMoving(Vector2 destination, Action action = null)
    {
        StartCoroutine(Move(destination, action));
    }

    IEnumerator Move(Vector3 destination, Action action = null)
    {
        float currentTime = 0;
        float perc = 0;
        Vector3 currentPos = transform.localPosition;

        while (perc != 1)
        {
            currentTime += Time.deltaTime;
            if (currentTime > moveTime)
            {
                currentTime = moveTime;
            }
            perc = moveSpeedCurve.Evaluate(currentTime / moveTime);
            transform.localPosition = Vector2.LerpUnclamped(currentPos, destination, movePositionCurve.Evaluate(perc));
            yield return null;
        }

        if (action != null)
            action();
    }
}
```